# How do i remove firebase access of an specific app id?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have an android app connected to firebase with app id test.example.com .

I removed the app from firebase by going into project settings > Remove app > Permanently delete app.

Even after deleting the project in firebase, I can access firebase services from the app test.example.com. Is there any way to revoke access so that firebase services like firestore and real time database won't work in test.example.com?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your [security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started) allow universal access to some collection, deleting the app from the console won't stop that access - the rules still allow that universal access.  If you want to stop that access, then update your rules to be more specific about the access you want to allow.

Ideally your rules need to check *who* can access the data, with the user being authenticated by Firebase Authentication.

Also consider using [App Check](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check) to help tighten up access so that only your registered apps can access the data (though it is not a guaranteed restriction).

If you choose not to do anything with rule, Firebase Auth, or App Check, then you must accept that access to your project data can come from anywhere by anyone.